# error while run npm unpublish - npm unpublish error

Tags: node.js, npm

I have error while run npm unpublish @mioun/letter-aneh -f

```
mioun@zde ~/miouns-7$ npm unpublish @mioun/letter-aneh -f
npm WARN using --force I sure hope you know what you are doing.
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - DELETE https://registry.npmjs.org/@mioun%2fletter-aneh/-rev/3-32e8cf92e0c9077ea473d6230a26359f - Not found
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404  '@mioun/letter-aneh@latest' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/mioun/.npm/_logs/2020-08-22T18_12_20_129Z-debug.log
```

Comment: same issue with me, did you manage to unpublish it?

Comment: yes right, do you know how to fix it?

Comment: This is authentication issue. Nothing to do with registry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a strange error. The actual issue was authentication issue. I had to

```
> npm logout
```

then

```
> npm login
```

this solved for me.